# Checking db for null values

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to find a way to insert a message into a textbox if the entry in a table is null or blank. I have tried the following code, but the textbox is not displaying the message. I know I have coded wrong but cannot see it.  Can someone please point out my error. Thanks

```
Private Sub UserDataGridView_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                  ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                                   Handles UserDataGridView.CellContentClick
  Dim value As Object = UserDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value
  Dim NoEdit As Object = UserDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value
  Dim InvCnt As Object = UserDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value
  Dim InvAddress As Object = UserDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value
  Dim Email As Object = UserDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value
  Dim Tel As Object = UserDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(5).Value
  Dim Fax As Object = UserDataGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(6).Value

  txtCustomerActive.Text = CType(value, String)
  txtCustomerNoedit.Text = CType(NoEdit, String)
  txtInvoiceContact.Text = CType(InvCnt, String)
  txtInvoiceAddress.Text = CType(InvAddress, String)
  txtEmail.Text = CType(Email, String)
  txtCustomerTelephone.Text = CType(Tel, String)

  If Fax Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Fax) Then
    txtCustomerFax.Text = "No Number on record" ' Display if no record
  Else
    txtCustomerFax.Text = CType(Fax, String)
  End If

  ' txtCustomerFax.Text = CType(Fax, String)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test also for a blank string because `IsDBNull` checks only for DBNull values, not for a blank string

```
 If Fax Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(Fax) OrElse Fax = string.Empty Then
    .....
```

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> IsDBNull returns True if the data type of Expression evaluates to the
>   DBNull type; otherwise, IsDBNull returns False.

Interesting comment below from @Arion, he suggests to use string.IsNullOrEmpty. 
So you could rewrite the test with only two calls

```
 If IsDBNull(Fax) OrElse string.IsNullOrEmpty(Fax) then
```

However it is important to test first for IsDBNull and then for IsNullOrEmpty because passing DBNull.Value to string.IsNullOrEmpty throws an exception

Comment: Why do you not use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`? And re-factor the rows to `If string.IsNullOrEmpty(Fax) OrElse IsDBNull(Fax) Then`

Comment: @Arion you are right, but it is important the order of test. If you have a DBNull.Value in Fax, you should test first for IsDBNull and then for string.IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: @Steve : Yes I think that it is less work to use the built in function for checking both NULL and empty. Yes I had a brain fart on the order of the validation =).+1: Of course you have to check dbnull before null or empty