# Check if Datatable Value is Null

Tags: c#, vb.net

Basically, I just want to ask how to check a datatable value if it is null or not? I am looping through each cells on the table, and check if the value of a cell is null.

I tried this

```
If Not dt.Rows(i)(j).value Is Nothing Then
   MsgBox("cell empty")
End If
```

and

```
If Not dt.Rows(i)(j).value = "" Then
   MsgBox("cell empty")
End If
```

but it is not working.

As of now, my datatable looks like this

"e" means empty

"ne" means not empty

"x" dont care

---

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 ... 

ne   x    x   ...

x    e    x   ...

x    x    x   ...
```

examples from the table above..

dt(0)(0) = ne

dt(1)(1) = e

dt(0)(1) = either "e" or "ne"

PS, **all the data in the datatable are all strings..**

how can I get the value if dt(1)(1) is empty? C# codes would be okay too..thanks

**EDIT:**

somehow, I've managed to solve my question by doing this, it met my requirement in my program so.. yea.

```
If dt.Rows(i)(j).Value.ToString = "" Then
   MsgBox("empty")
End If
```

thanks. Please close the thread.

Comment: [Best way to check if a Data Table has a null value in it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4604459/3089494)

Comment: If you have found the answer, post it as a separate answer and accept it! It would help in maintaining the essence of StackOverflow.

Comment: I think you can close yourself question via vote for close? or you accept the one suggest you to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Compare the value to `DBNull.Value`.

```
foreach(DataRow row in myTable.Rows)
{
    object value = row["column"];
    if (value == DBNull.Value)
        // do something
    else
        // do something else
}
```

This was also answered on a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604414/best-way-to-check-if-a-data-table-has-a-null-value-in-it).

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx

you can use IsDBNull method

```
while (dr.Read())
{
  dr.GetValues(fieldValues);

  for (int fieldCounter = 0; fieldCounter < fieldCount; fieldCounter++)
  {
     if (Convert.IsDBNull(fieldValues[fieldCounter]))
        fieldValues[fieldCounter] = "NA";
  }
  grid.Rows.Add(fieldValues);


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)dt.Rows[i][j].value))
{
  MsgBox("cell empty");
}
else
{
 MsgBox("cell is not empty")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For VB.net

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222834/handling-dbnull-data-in-vb-net), sorry I'm not sure what to check inside the IsDbNull (if wrong please forgive me) because I have no experience deal with database in vb.net.

### **If wrong**, please comment me to **fix it**, thanks.

```
If NOT IsDbNull(dt.Rows(i)(j)) Then
   MsgBox("cell non-empty")
ELSE
   MsgBox("cell empty")
End If
```

OR check much more than only DbNull like accepted answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295156/checking-db-for-null-values)

```
If IsDBNull(dt.Rows(i)(j)) OrElse dt.Rows(i)(j).Value.ToString Is Nothing OrElse dt.Rows(i)(j).Value.ToString = string.Empty Then
   MsgBox("cell empty")
```

1. If I want to check `IsDBNull()`, I should put `dt.Rows(i)(j)` or
   `dt.Rows(i)(j).Value` to check?
2. If I want to check `Is Nothing`, I should put `dt.Rows(i)(j)` or
   `dt.Rows(i)(j).Value`  or `dt.Rows(i)(j).Value.ToString`to check?

thanks. Sorry for ask questions in question....